# Sorted List insertion keeps creating new head?

Tags: java, tree, linked-list, sortedlist

Everytime I want to insert a new node into the list it will make a new head, which it should do the first time, but the second time it should attach the new node to the previous one. Whenever I insert with this code it keeps creating a new head. Why does the previous head which was first inserted not being saved?

```
static class TreeNode{
    int frequency;
    boolean isLeftChild;
    TreeNode parent;
    TreeNode next;

    /**
     * TreeNode class constructor to initialize the variables and also
     * takes a frequency as the parameter.
     * @param f Frequency of a certain character.
     */
    TreeNode(int f){
        frequency = f;
        isLeftChild = true;
        parent = null;
        next = null;
    }
}

// Class used to store information for the linked list.
static class List{
    TreeNode head;
    int numItems; // number of nodes in the list

    List(){
        head = null;
        numItems = 0;
        // initialize head and numItems
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a node into the TreeNode linked list according to its frequencies
     * position as it will be in a SORTED list.
     * @param freq Frequency of a specific character.
     * @return Returns the new TreeNode object that has been inserted.
     */
    TreeNode insert(int freq){
        TreeNode previous, current, newNode;
        int newFreq = freq;
        numItems++;

        previous = null;
        current = head;
        while((current != null) && (Integer.valueOf(newFreq).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(current.frequency)) > 0 )){
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        if(previous == null){
            head = new TreeNode(newFreq);
            return head;

        }
        else{
            newNode = new TreeNode(newFreq);
            previous.next = newNode;
            return newNode;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you never set the new node's next pointer?

Comment: What happens if you try to insert something less than the current head's frequency?

Comment: I think I have a good guess at what's wrong here. Can you tell me which values you are inserting?

Comment: @liangricha I am inserting different Frequencies for each TreeNode object. As long as a frequency is greater than 0 it will be inserted into the list. It is also using a sorted list insertion method so that the head on the linked list will be the smallest value.

Comment: Which frequencies do you insert that caused the error?

Comment: @liangricha the first frequency that gets added in is 8 and the next is 7 then 4 and finally 1, the list should be sorted so the head is 1 then 4 then 7 and finally the last node is 8.

Comment: I posted an answer below. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

If the head should only be created once, then that's what the constructor is for!

```
List() {
    // initialize head here
    head = new Node();
    head.next = head;
    head.previous = head;
}
```

Also, I think you need to think a bit longer about what you want your list's nodes to look like. Do I understand correctly that you're trying to create a doubly linked sorted list? If so, it's probably of most use if its nodes contain data objects of type `Comparabe`, so that you can reuse the list for other purposes. (Even fancier would be to make its data type generic `Comparable<T>`.)

Finally, if you're trying to store frequencies of letters in the list, then the data type will need to have two fields, one for the letter's frequency and one for the letter it's counting. And you'll have to decide which of the two you wish to use for sorting: the character or the frequency. I'd expect the character.

Anyways, try to draw a little picture first of what you'd like to do, before you start coding away.

Comment: Yeah but in my main program when I create the list the head should be null and the first node that I insert will then become the head. The problem is after I am inserting the next node I can't figure out why it isn't setting the pointer to the head. So the first TreeNode would = head and head.next should be the second TreeNode.

Comment: @user3001301 Why should it be null first? I'd think that complicates things unnecessarily. I've added some code to show how the head can initially be its own next and previous element.

Comment: If you noticed I'm using my own TreeNode object node so that is why it is coded that such way. The TreeNode object will be used later to construct a tree, thus the reason why I'm using tree's in the first place.

Comment: A tree node has a parent and children. A doubly linked list has a previous and a next pointer. They're two different things. Try to use one class for one purpose. This makes your code easier to understand and create. So if you later want to construct a tree, at that time write a method that does the conversion from list to tree.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take a stab at this:

Say that you first insert `TreeNode`s of frequencies 5 and 4, in that order. As you said, the first insertion will occur as intended. When you attempt to insert the `TreeNode` with frequency 4, the `while(...)` will be bypassed immediately, meaning that current is still the `TreeNode` with frequency 5, and previous is still `null`. According to your code, this will cause the Linked List to create a new head, and overwrite the previous one.

In short, you are not assigning correctly if the TreeNode with frequency you inserted is less than the frequency of the head. To correct this, something like this should be added after your while loop:

```
if(current == head) {
  newNode = new TreeNode(newFreq);
  newNode.next = head;
  head = newNode;
}
```

Also, in the "else" part if your if/else statement, you are not assigning the "next" field of `newNode`, so this statement should be added:

`newNode.next = current;`